# Values that we are getting in user defined data variable is not same as data points graph

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

This is the script we are getting the value for "durationTime".

```
Action()
{
float durationTime;
 lr_start_transaction("1st Load Test");       
 web_url("user_guide","URL=http://www.espncricinfo.com","Mode=HTML",LAST ); 
 durationTime = lr_get_transaction_duration("1st Load Test");
 lr_output_message("----Duration time of URL----: [%f]", durationTime);
 lr_user_data_point("duration_Time", durationTime);
 lr_end_transaction("1st Load Test", LR_AUTO);
return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

----Duration time of URL----: [4.460504]

Can anyone please clarify, whether we need to change anything in graph settings or other ways to do this.

[But in analysis report data point graph getting different values, for reference attached the screenshot of graph data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwPXb.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify the rational use of reporting the transaction time twice.  Also, you will need to remove think time and wasted time to get the time reported by default in analysis

Comment: This appears to be a part of an odd set of questions on this same datapoint collection and reporting topic on download time using an alternate method appearing on Facebook, GoogleGroups, LinkedIn, Stackoverflow, etc...   Can someone shed light on the source for all of these questions on an odd topic in the past week?